# Check if pipe is empty before writing

Tags: perl, pipe, buffering

I have inherited a perl program which opens a pipe to another program:

```
open(CONSUMER, "|/bin/consumer >> logfile 2>&1") ||
    die "Comsumer open fail\n";
select(CONSUMER); $| = 1;
```

and then repeatedly writes to this pipe in a loop:

```
while (<INPUT>) {
    $command=$_;
    ...
#   is CONSUMER empty?
    print CONSUMER $command;
}
```

It seems that a bunch of these commands get buffered up in the pipe buffer.  This monopolizes the service that CONSUMER is using.  At some point this:

```
select(undef, undef, undef, 0.1);
```

got added to the bottom of the loop as a (not very effective) bandaid.

It seems that what would be most effective is if there could be a check in front of the `print` to make sure the pipe buffer was empty before proceeding with the `print`.

Is this at all possible?

Comment: Off topic, but the cryptic `select(CONSUMER); $| = 1;` is better written as `CONSUMER->autoflush;` in modern Perls.

Comment: It sounds like you have more work (commands) than the consumer is able to support. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, this script can read commands (from the file) a lot faster than consumer can process them.  The problem is this starves other things trying to use consumer.

Comment: Yes, the pipe is getting full if the reader is slower or absent. Once it gets "full" (normally 64k) it will block. One cannot check for not-empty; we can check whether we can write to it (whether it is not-full). So the `/bin/consumer` is too slow and the faster writing to it makes it work only with this script all the time? What is wrong with `0.1s` sleep (that added `select`), and why is it "not very effective"? Without access to `consumer`'s code one other way I can think of is to monitor `logfile`, but that's surely not nice, and `consumer`'s output is likely buffered anyway.

Comment: We don't know enough about the situation to help. It sounds like the design is badly wrong. Is this process just reading commands from a file and passing them to `consumer`? Do the other sources of commands work the same way? If so then you can create just a single process that reads a command from each of the files in rotation and passes it to `consumer` to create round-robin scheduling. If there is something else in play then please describe it *in detail*. You have given only the tiniest amount of information about what is a relatively complex situation. We can't help you by guesswork.

Comment: Re "*This monopolizes the service that CONSUMER is using*", Sounds like something you need to fix in the service. "*Oh? It's been that long since I've done something other than service CONSUMER? Then I'll do the other things I need to do before going back to servicing CONSUMER.*"

Comment: The other users of the service are "interactive" (i.e. Web) users hence the concern with their starvation by this bulk update.  The sleep is ineffective because the commands take a highly variable amount of time to complete. I do not at present have time for a complete re-architecting of this thing, hence my search for a quick win.

Comment: How about you run it as an external command (blocking), instead as a constant feed over a pipe, plain and simple? Loop over input like you do and run `consumer `; it's a small tweak, not a major rewrite. Then others get a chance to fight for it, or you can _then_ add a little sleep as well.

Comment: Commands you write on pipe are already defined? Can you follow each command with a dummy/special command like touching a file or a record update to check for completion on the true command?

Comment: This has probably never worked right but when Linux increased the pipe buffer size from 4K to 64K just made it completely unworkable.  Thank you all for convincing me of what I feared - there is no easy way out - the only solution is a rewrite.